# How do I use the ogrinfo's -json option to return the result of the SQL query?

Tags: gdal, json, ogrinfo

I crate an example GPKG, `example.gpkg`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(dict(
        geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0]),
                  shapely.geometry.Point([1, 1]),
                  shapely.geometry.Point([1, 1])],
        col0=["a","b","b"]))

gdf.to_file("example.gpkg",driver="GPKG")
```

It contains:

```
                  geometry col0
0  POINT (0.00000 0.00000)    a
1  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)    b
2  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)    b
```

I would like to use `ogrinfo` to get a list of unique values in a column, in this case: `col0`. I do:

```
ogrinfo -sql "
    SELECT DISTINCT col0 FROM example
" example.gpkg \
| grep "col0 (String) = " \
| sed 's/  col0 (String) = //g' \
> values.lst
```

Which works on Mac OS. `cat values.lst`:

```
a
b
```

But this is not very interoperable, as `sed` may not work the same way on Debian & Mac. It would be good to make `ogrinfo` return something which is easier to process than a human-readable text output. Perhaps a [`json`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html#cmdoption-ogrinfo-json)? Processing would be easy then with `jq`. I try:

```
ogrinfo -json -sql "
    SELECT DISTINCT col0 FROM example
" example.gpkg
```

Output:

```
{
  "description":"example.gpkg",
  "driverShortName":"GPKG",
  "driverLongName":"GeoPackage",
  "layers":[
    {
      "name":"SELECT",
      "metadata":{},
      "geometryFields":[],
      "featureCount":2,
      "fields":[
        {
          "name":"col0",
          "type":"String",
          "nullable":true,
          "uniqueConstraint":false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata":{},
  "domains":{},
  "relationships":{}
}
```

This output does not have `a` & `b`, so I cannot extract them with `jq`.

**How do I use the `ogrinfo`'s `-json` option to return the result of the SQL query?**

If I know the answer to this, I'll be able to figure out how to process the result with `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html I would have a try with `-features`.

> -features
>
> Enable listing of features. This has the opposite effect of -so.
>
> This option should be used with caution if using the library function
> GDALVectorInfo() and/or -json, as the whole output of ogrinfo will be
> built in memory. Consequently, when used on a large collection of
> features, RAM may be exhausted.